# Why can't I install android on my windows 11 machine?

Tags: android, windows-11

I'm trying to be able to install android apps on my Windows 11 machine.

https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/10/20/announcing-android-apps-on-windows-11-preview-for-windows-insiders-in-the-beta-channel/

So, I'm trying to install the Amazon Appstore app. The Microsoft Store app will not let me install it. The Microsoft Store app says "This app will not work on your device."

### What have I tried?

#### Stated requirements

There are several requirements. Most are marked as checked by the Windows Store app:

- ✅ PC
- ✅ OS: Win 11
- ✅ Architecture: 64 bit
- ✅ Memory
- Processor: Intel Core i3 8th Generation . . . or above
- Notes: Insider Channel Beta minimum

[image: Store Screenshot]

So, only two of the above aren't checked:

- Processor

  - System -> about -> Device Specifications -> `Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz 2.59 GHz`
  - So, this is a 10th generation i7. It should exceed requirements.
- Release Channel

  - `winver` -> Version Dev (OS Build 22489.1000).
  - So, I'm on the Dev release channel. It should exceed requirements.

[image: winver cropped]

So I think I meet the stated requirements, but for some reason I can't understand, Windows doesn't think I do.

#### Other Guesses I tried.

I thought it might be because of virtualization support, but I discovered can run Ubuntu on WSL, which requires the same capabilities.

So I'm at a loss. I think I meet or exceed all requirements. Why can't I install android app support?

Comment: What version of Windows 11 are you using? You can run `winver` to find out, we will need full build info.

Comment: First you need the preview channel of Win 11 and second this beta feature is at the moment only available in USA.

Comment: 10th generation Core processors are fully supported under Windows 11. **Sounds like you simply don't have a compatible Windows 11 build install.** 10th generation Core Intel processor exceeds the requirements for an 8th generation Core Intel processor.  Which by the way includes the equivalent AMD processors.  **Basically you must be running a processor Windows 11 supports.**

Comment: I'm currently on the Dev release channel. `winver` -> Version Dev (OS Build 22483.1011). Is that somehow not the beta?

Comment: System -> about -> Device Specifications -> Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, you've basically restated my question. There are two features not checked that I think I meet. I'm asking this question because it doesn't make sense to me. So I don't understand the purpose of your comment. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I have edited for clarity as to why I think it doesn't work, and why I think it should work anyway. I'm still at a loss.

Comment: So I can’t tell if you have installed WSA on your machine. You checked those requirements, they should be checked, the fact they are not checked is simply because you didn’t check them.

Comment: @Ramhound according to [this resource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/android/wsa/#set-up-your-development-environment) Windows Subsystem for Android is installed automatically when installing the Amazon Appstore app. This is the difficulty I have that started this question. I cannot install the amazon appstore app on my computer, and the reasons it gives are not clear, hence the question I asked.

Comment: What errors do you receive when you attempt to install the Amazon App Store? Your question only has your suspicions about your processor, being incompatible with Windows 11, which are not accurate. It wouldn’t hurt to provide a screenshot of **winver** that shows which build of Windows 11 you have installed

Comment: @Ramhound I already put the error message up, as well as the winver results (in text form). If you'd prefer images as well, I can do that too.

Comment: @Ramhound My question states the current problems the store is giving me. They're not *my* suspicions, they're the windows store "suspicions".

Comment: @McKay - Your question didn't make it clear the requirements were from the application listing, what you said, was clear as dirt from that perspective.  It wasn't until the screenshot did I understand the question.  Just out of curiosity to make sure you are finding the correct application within the store, [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-subsystem-for-android-with-amazon-appstore/9p3395vx91nr?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), appears to be what you should actually be attempting to install.  You are 100% sure your Microsoft Store is set to a supported region?

Comment: @McKay - Can you provide the version of the Microsoft Store you have installed? You will want to verify it's at least 22110.1401.10.0

Comment: @Ramhound My windows App store version is "22110.1401.12.0". Is there a reason that I would need this in an image as well? I don't see why it's necessary, but I can provide that as well, if you'd like.

Comment: @Ramhound The first link in my question talks about the process I was following. It wasn't telling me to install the Android Subsystem app, but the [Amazon Appstore app](http://aka.ms/AmazonAppstore). The Microsoft link says the Android Subsystem app is installed with the store app.

Comment: @Ramhound But I was able to install the Android Subsystem app. (it does nothing when I launch it, but I presume that might be as intended?)

Comment: Did you try the link I provided?

Comment: @Ramhound The link you provided takes me to a Microsoft Store app called "Windows Subsystem for Android™ with Amazon Appstore". My comment immediately preceding yours states that I was able to install the Android Subsystem. By that, I meant "Windows Subsystem for Android™ with Amazon Appstore" that I found following your link. It does not do anything when launched. (And by that I mean it opens a window which has "Windows Subsystem for Android™" as it's title, but it is just a white box.) Nor does it assist where I am with my original question in trying to follow Microsoft's instructions.