# Windows store shows storage not supported even I have installed windows on SSD

Tags: windows, ssd, android, windows-11

I am trying to install [Windows Subsystem for Android with Amazon Appstore](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-subsystem-for-android/9p3395vx91nr?activetab=pivot:regionofsystemrequirementstab).

I am getting below warning

> Your storage device isn't supported for this product.

I have installed windows 11 on my SSD drive.

[image]
[image]

Device Specification:

- Processor  AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx     2.00 GHz
- Installed RAM  8.00 GB (6.90 GB usable)
- Device ID  device-id
- Product ID product-id
- System type    64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
- Pen and touch  No pen or touch input is available for this display

Windows Specification

- Edition    Windows 11 Home Insider Preview Single Language
- Version    Dev
- Installed on   ‎12/‎4/‎2021
- OS build   22509.1011
- Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22509.1011.0

[image: Drive Storage Space Details]

[image: Hyper-v is enabled]
[image: Virtualization is Enabled]

Comment: The error message seems nonsensical indeed. WSA requires a SSD and you have one so it should be fine. There's a chance this has to do with something else, namely virtualization not enabled in UEFI. Or you might not be in the USA...

Comment: It might also be worth to check the installation settings for the Windows Store. It might be trying to use the bigger drive, maybe due to the (download) size. Depending on how full the C drive already is there might not be enough space.

Comment: I have the same processor but i think its not supported by win11. Maybe there's a stupid check which fails because of the incompatible processor.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have enabled virtualization, I will attach the image.

Comment: Thanks. Confirming it is enough though. Me and I guess everybody else is just guessing at this point. Seth's hypotheses is very promising and makes sense considering the specific error message.

Comment: WSL only runs on the system drive. Have you perhaps installed it on the D: drive? ([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting))

Comment: @harrymc I am not talking about WSL. Also, I have installed windows on C drive only, see the attached images.

Comment: @Seth There is enough sapce in C: drive, see the image.

Comment: @8bitIcon - I suspect the reason you are getting this error is because you are running Windows 11 in an unsupported configuration.  Windows 11 does not formally support your processor according to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-11-supported-amd-processors) list of supported processors.  [When you installed Windows 11 did you enable the registry key that allows you to bypass the processor check?](https://superuser.com/questions/1682450/)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1683111/why-cant-i-install-android-on-my-windows-11-machine)

Comment: In your Task Manager screenshot, `Disk 0` is listed as an `HDD`. This probably indicates that the SATL does not translate ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE result properly to a Block device characteristics VPD page (assuming Samsung does not suck enough on their firmware). I am betting that you are not using the Microsoft AHCI driver but one from AMD, and the driver is doing a bad job. (Consider showing which driver you are using with a Device Manager screenshot.)

Comment: @Ramhound No, I just simply open the setup and it started installing.

Answer (score 1):

**Judging by your Task Manager screenshot (that your SSD is listed as an HDD)**, the cause of the problem is probably either your SSD's firmware or the (software) [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_/_ATA_Translation) layer provided by your SATA/AHCI driver is not reporting / translating the corresponding information (that the drive is non-rotating) properly. (With a second thought, it could also be that in your UEFI settings, your SATA controller is not configured to operate in AHCI mode...)

Check whether you are using the Microsoft AHCI driver (`Standard SATA AHCI Controller`) or a driver from AMD in Device Manager (under `IDE ATA/ATAPI Controllers`). If it's the latter case, you might want to consider uninstalling it. **(I do NOT guarantee that it will not break booting.)**

You may also use programs (needs to be run with Administrator Windows Terminal / Command Prompt) in sg3_utils ([click this to download the last working version](https://sg.danny.cz/sg/p/sg3_utils-1.46mgw64.zip)) to confirm that your drive's firmware is doing its job fine and the SAT layer is indeed bad.

Firmware (Word 217 / 0xd9 being `0x0001` states that the drive is non-rotating):

```
PS C:\Users\tom\Downloads\sg3_utils-1.46mgw64> .\sg_sat_identify.exe PD0
Response for IDENTIFY DEVICE ATA command:
...
 d8     0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 10ff 0000     .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..
...
```

SAT layer:

```
PS C:\Users\tom\Downloads\sg3_utils-1.46mgw64> .\sg_vpd -p bdc PD0
Block device characteristics VPD page (SBC):
  Non-rotating medium (e.g. solid state)
...
```

What you *might* see when the produced VPD is not "good enough":

```
PS C:\Users\tom\Downloads\sg3_utils-1.46mgw64> .\sg_vpd -p bdc PD1
Block device characteristics VPD page (SBC):
  Medium rotation rate is not reported
...
```

(There's also a chance that it does not produce this particular VPD page at all.)

For your reference:
[image]

Comment: It's also possible the system requirement check is indicating a incompatibility for the wrong system requirement.  The author's processor isn't technically supported by Windows 11.  Microsoft's compatibility check for Windows 11 is known to have problems (specifically on the corner compatibility cases)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1006877/windows-10-optimize-drives-shows-ssd-as-hard-disk-drive suggests running `winsat diskformal` or `winsat formal` might redetect the SSD and clear up it being reported as an HDD, as well as some other options to do with Intel Rapid storage.

Comment: @Tom Yan It's AMD Sata Controller

Comment: As suggested in the answer, you can use `sg_vpd.exe` to confirm whether the SATL is actually bad. If that's the case, what you might want to attempt (with risk) is to uninstall the AMD driver (by right clicking on the controller and choose uninstall device, optionally checking the delete driver box in the prompt as well).

Comment: Actually, it might be a must to check the delete driver box in the prompt, otherwise after rebooting there might be no actual effect (the AMD driver remains being used).

Comment: @TomYan Getting
  .\sg_vpd -p bdc PD0
fetching VPD page failed: Domain error
sg_vpd failed: Domain error

Comment: .\sg_sat_identify.exe PD0 this gives the exact response though  d8     0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 10ff 0000

Comment: I tried uninstalling both AMD Sata Controller and Also SSD listed in Disk Drives,  both from device manager window, it still shows HDD in task maanger.

Comment: Hmm, what do you see under `IDE ATA/ATAPI Controllers` now? And what does `sg_vpd.exe` shows you now?

Comment: @TomYan Same, AMD Sata Controller

Comment: Ahh, I suppose you didn't check the delete driver box in the prompt? You probably want to do it again with the box checked. (But again, I do NOT guarantee that it's risk-free.)

Answer (score 0):

The message "Your storage device isn’t supported for this product"
is misleading. It is likely that the prerequisites for
Windows Subsystem for Android have not been satisfied.

Here is the list of the prerequisites:

- Your VM/computer needs to meet the
  [minimum hardware requirements](https://www.itechtics.com/windows-11-requirements-check/)
  for Windows 11
- Virtualization support must be enabled
- Your device should be subscribed to the Beta channel
- The Windows 11 build must be at least 22000.xxx
- The Microsoft Store version must be at least 22110.1402.6.0
- Computer region must be set to U.S
- Have a U.S.-based Amazon Appstore account.

For more information, see the article
[How to Run Android Apps on Windows 11 Right Now (Without Emulator)](https://www.itechtics.com/android-apps-windows-11/).

Note: These prerequisites will surely change in the future.