# Minimum processor requirements for WSA on Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I have mini PC running Intel Celeron J4105. I earlier installed Windows Subsytem for Android successfully, though the app experience wasn't that great in those initial days. Sites like these say that Microsoft will officially support Windows 11 on my processor: [1](https://www.xda-developers.com/cpus-compatible-windows-11/), [2](https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-support-windows-11-intel-amd-qualcomm-processors/).

Few days back I uninstalled WSA and now trying to reinstall. But it now says this:

(Notice it says "Your processor isn't supported for this product.")
[image]

Are minimum requirements for WSA changed?

Comment: Did you install Windows 11 on this computer?

Comment: Didnt get... Screenshot says requirement for "Windows 11 version 22000.120 or higher" is satisfied. So, yes I am indeed trying on Windows 11.

Comment: Your computer does not seem to support TPM. This means that proper functioning is not absolutely guaranteed.

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1691512/windows-store-shows-storage-not-supported-even-i-have-installed-windows-on-ssd/1691541#1691541) is a semi-related question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Your processor isn't supported for this product

You have a Intel Celeron J4105 process so it would appear not.

> **Prerequisites**
>
> Windows Subsystem for Android is available for public preview on
> Windows 11.
>
> Your device must meet specific requirements: [Device requirements](https://support.microsoft.com/windows/f8d0abb5-44ad-47d8-b9fb-ad6b1459ff6c).

Source: [Windows Subsystem for Android™️ | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/android/wsa/)

> **Device requirements**
>
> Processor
>
> - Intel Core i3 8th Gen (minimum) or above
> - AMD Ryzen 3000 (minimum) or above
> - Qualcomm Snapdragon 8c (minimum) or above

Source: [Install mobile apps and the Amazon Appstore](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/install-mobile-apps-and-the-amazon-appstore-f8d0abb5-44ad-47d8-b9fb-ad6b1459ff6c)

Comment: well, but I does indeed installed and uninstalled WSA couple of months back ... so now am guessing how it was possible ... or they have changed the minimum requirements in new updates ...

Comment: Now I recall I installed WSA from [this](https://store.rg-adguard.net/) site and not from Store something as explained in [this](https://youtu.be/xc3zf21qx2k?t=51) video.

Answer (score 1):

The article
[Hardware requirements Android apps on Windows 11](https://winaero.com/here-are-the-hardware-requirements-for-running-android-apps-on-windows-11/)
dated February 18, 2022, has a fuller list of the requirements:

> - Windows 11. No Android apps for older versions.
> - Minimum 8 GB of RAM, 16 GB recommended.
> - Solid State Drive (SSD). Legacy hard drives are not supported.
> - CPU: x64 Intel Core i3 8th gen or newer; AMD Ryzen 3000 (Zen2) or newer; ARM64 Qualcomm Snapdragon 8c or newer.
> - UEFI and Windows configuration: You should enable Virtual Machine Platform before installing Android apps on Windows 11.

This explains why your CPU in unacceptable for WSA on Windows 11.

Comment: well, but I does indeed installed and uninstalled WSA couple of months back ... so now am guessing how it was possible ... or they have changed the minimum requirements in new updates ...

Comment: Now I recall I installed WSA from [this](https://store.rg-adguard.net/) site and not from Store something as explained in [this](https://youtu.be/xc3zf21qx2k?t=51) video.

Comment: You might have installed an older pre-Windows 11 version of WSA, that had a different CPU check. This might mean that the current requirements are too high.

Comment: Or I can still install new version following above approach? Am guessing what checks the requirements, the package itself or the store. If it is store, then I believe it might still work ...

Comment: All you can do is try, with the older version as fall-back.